# why the html5 geolocation fails to get results?

Tags: html, geolocation

On what basis does HTML 5 geolocation work ? Does it guess the location on the basis of IP address ? I guess it doesn't need a GPS enabled device ? I do not have GPS on my laptop.

I have been trying to test my location using HTML5 geolocation on [w3schools geolocation tester/demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) and [html5demos](http://html5demos.com/geo) but I either get *location information unavailable* or *failed*.  What could be the reason for this ?

*Note :* I am connected to internet via USB Tethering.

Comment: Youv'e probably disabled the "Get physical location" (or something like that) setting in your browser. Usually, you should get a prompt which requests permission to get this geo data.

Comment: @RobW when it asks for permission,I  always grant it

Comment: @RobW I grant the permission when it asks but still , is there any troubleshooting mechanism that I can follow to detect the actual problem ?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly the browser does geolocation is up to it. If it has access to a GPS device, it may use that. Otherwise it may do GSM triangulation, reverse IP geolocation, WiFi network database lookups or anything else it can or can't do.

It depends on your browser/OS and is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: _"not guaranteed to work_".  Heard this for the first time ! I am using _firefox 15_ on _linux (fedora)_. If there is a feature introduced _geolocation_ in html5 it should work with this combination

Comment: If the computer cannot geolocate itself, it simply does not work. It will give you the best value it can, but there's no guarantee it can give you anything useful. The HTML5 geolocation API is just a standardized API, it does not make the location process work automagically under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It will works in most circumstances on a direct connection. However, if it connected via Proxy/VPN, sometimes it will fail to geolocate the position. Just some sharing of my last encounters found.