# Finding the accurate location of a given IP address within 50miles

Tags: php, dictionary, ip-address, zipcode

In my page I used a functionality of finding Geolocation of a given IP address. This returns result of particular location with zipcode.

But this zipcode is not accurate one. The difference of the zipcodes I got from coding and the real location is about more than 200 miles. I used the following code from ip2location website.

```
require_once('ip2location.class.php');

$ip = new ip2location;
$ip->open('./databases/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-LATITUDE-LONGITUDE-ZIPCODE-TIMEZONE-ISP-DOMAIN-NETSPEED-AREACODE-WEATHER-MOBILE-SAMPLE.BIN');

$record = $ip->getAll('50.178.183.243');

echo '<b>IP Address:</b> ' . $record->ipAddress . '<br>';
echo '<b>IP Number:</b> ' . $record->ipNumber . '<br>';
echo '<b>Country Short:</b> ' . $record->countryShort . '<br>';
echo '<b>Country Long:</b> ' . $record->countryLong . '<br>';
echo '<b>Region:</b> ' . $record->region . '<br>';
echo '<b>City:</b> ' . $record->city . '<br>';
echo '<b>ISP/Organisation:</b> ' . $record->isp . '<br>';
echo '<b>Latitude:</b> ' . $record->latitude . '<br>';
echo '<b>Longitude:</b> ' . $record->longitude . '<br>';
echo '<b>Domain:</b> ' . $record->domain . '<br>';
echo '<b>ZIP Code:</b> ' . $record->zipCode . '<br>';
echo '<b>Time Zone:</b> ' . $record->timeZone . '<br>';
echo '<b>Net Speed:</b> ' . $record->netSpeed . '<br>';
echo '<b>IDD Code:</b> ' . $record->iddCode . '<br>';
echo '<b>Area Code:</b> ' . $record->areaCode . '<br>';
echo '<b>Weather Station Code:</b> ' . $record->weatherStationCode . '<br>';
echo '<b>Weather Station Name:</b> ' . $record->areaCode . '<br>';
echo '<b>MCC:</b> ' . $record->mcc . '<br>';
echo '<b>MNC:</b> ' . $record->mnc . '<br>';
echo '<b>Mobile Brand:</b> ' . $record->mobileBrand . '<br>';
?>
```

I tried the coding in so many websites such as

- http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup
- http://www.ipinfodb.com
- http://www.fraudlabs.com
- http://www.ip2location.com/

But I didn't get the actual result. Accurate zipcode is not found in the above websites for the give IP address. Anybody can help me to solve this issue. Thanks for reading and solve this issue in advance.

Comment: Did you try using [Geocoder](http://geocoder-php.org/)?

Comment: No, I didn't see the Geocoder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is hazy by design, and it's nothing you can easily fix. IP-based geolocation services can only use the position information they guess from the various points from their server to the target IP. (You can see those points when you do a `traceroute <targetip>` on your console). How exact IP geolocation is depends on your user's ISP's architecture, and results can be *way* off in some areas, but pretty exact in others (especially cities).

If you seriously need exact geolocation, use [client-side HTML 5 geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo). This requires the user's consent, though, and can be imprecise as well if the client device doesn't have a GPS.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the great answer. I will try client-side HTML 5 geolocation

Comment: @Rithu then your device may not have any method to determine its location. [why the html5 geolocation fails to get results?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13109696)

Comment: @Rithu I get a pretty good result with this though: http://maxheapsize.com/static/html5geolocationdemo.html (on a Macbook, no GPS, accuracy 20 *meters*)

Comment: What input we have to give in that search box

Comment: @Rithu none - your browser should ask you whether it can tell the web site your location. (Chrome and Firefox at least). You should see your location on the map then.

Comment: But this page shows "You location is: Unknown." But I dont know why it shows like that. +1 for the great answer.

Comment: @Rithu did the browser ask you whether it can reveal your location to the site? What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome browser. But this page didn't ask anything.

Comment: But I'm very proud to get your answer for my question and very glad to see your answers and comments. Thank you so much. I want to learn several new things from you.

Comment: @Rithu no problem. Hmmm, that's strange though. I get a bar to the top of the page asking me whether I want to allow geolocation. Not sure why it doesn't come up for you. Maybe that happens though if there are no location capabilities in the machine